# Completed tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, formal-groups

I want to know if this notion of [completed tensor product](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AMU) is the one that yields $$ k[\![ x ]\!] \hat{\otimes}  k[\![ y ]\!] \cong  k[\![ x,y ]\!]. $$ Here I should be considering the inverse limit topology in the power series rings, and $R=k$ a field (with the trivial topology?). If it is not, then what is the right notion of $ \hat{\otimes}$ ?

I believe this is broadly used when talking of formal groups laws (eg defining its contravariant bialgebra).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this completed tensor product yields the identity.

Before explaining the answer let me point out that $k$ is indeed considered with the discrete topology and the power series ring with the inverse limit topology.

A vector subspace of $k[[ x ]]$ is open in this topology if and only if it contains the ideal generated by $x^n$ for some $n$.
It follows that ideals $\langle x^n\rangle\subset k[[ x]]$ are open subspaces of $k[[ x]]$ and define a fundamental system of open subspaces. Thus we have
$$
 \lim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K[[ x]] / \langle x^n\rangle = \lim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K[ x] / \langle x^n\rangle = K[[ x]]
$$
as one easily verifies. (This is now moreover an isomorphism of topological vector spaces.)
For the tensor product, we get the same computation in a slightly more complicated way
$$
  K[[ x]] \widehat{\otimes} K[[ y ]]
= \lim_{m,n} K[[ x]] / \langle x^n\rangle \otimes  K[[ y]] / \langle y^m\rangle
= \lim_{m,n} K[x,y] / \langle x^n, y^m \rangle
= K[[ x,y ]]
$$
which answers your Question.